# How to delete a previous iteration in a Python loop?

Tags: python, iteration

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have a large text document made up of many books. All the books have "running headers" and I have noticed that they appear just before the line of the page number. The page number has 1 to 4 digit. The page number is on a new line.

I want to iterate through the file and make Python to delete the previous iteration when it gets to the line that starts with a page number.

Thanks

Bennett

My sample code is:

```
import re
f=open("corpus.txt", "r+", "a")
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('^[0-9]*?', line):
        #delete previous line
```

Comment: What do you mean by "delete an iteration"? An iteration is something a loop does - it is not data that can be deleted.

Comment: What are you doing with the lines? If you're appending them to a list, you can simply delete that element of the list.

Comment: @kaya3 I think he means to undo the previous iteration's results.

Comment: You can't go back. The easiest method is to always keep track of the last 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
file = open(r"C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\sample.txt").read().splitlines()
output = open(r"C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\output.txt",'w')
for index, line in enumerate(file):
    try:
        if file[index+1].strip().isdigit() == False and file[index].strip().isdigit() == False:
            output.write(file[index])
            output.write('\n')
    except:    
        output.write(file[index])  #printing last line
        output.write('\n')
output.close()
```

Input:

```
wearing sandals, a cock that crows, a cloak
to dissect, a sponge, some vinegar and one
man to hammer the nails home.
56

Or you can take a length of steel,
castle to hold your banquet in.
77

wearing sandals, a cock that crows, a cloak
to dissect, a sponge, some vinegar and one
```

Output:

```
wearing sandals, a cock that crows, a cloak
to dissect, a sponge, some vinegar and one

Or you can take a length of steel,

wearing sandals, a cock that crows, a cloak
to dissect, a sponge, some vinegar and one
```

Comment: Thanks Vinod. Honestly I am still trying to understand how your code works. But I have the whole idea.

Comment: It just converts text file to list of lines and and for loop checks its element. And based on next element it decides to write current element in output file.